# SwiftUI Click image in grid and display adjacent frame (First App for Autistic Son)

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui

So this is litterally my first attempt at using swift and it is a learning experience for myself. I hope to eventually use this very simple app for my autistic son. The goal is to have a long list of objects he lights to select from on the left hand side of his iPad. If he clicks on an item, I want it to appear on the right hand side and to let him click on the image and for a sound playing naming it.

So far this is what I have

[image: App Preview Right now]

I need to figure out how to turn the action of the button on the select into displaying it on the right.

Secondly, white I have figured out how to playsound from the grid, I would like to make sure it can be played from the item displayed on the right.

Here is the code for the grid, and the right hand side is just a placeholder image at the moment.

[image: Grid Code]

If there is a resource that I shoulfd look at that I'm missing, please just point me in that direction. I appreciate and feedback/help. Thank you so much.

I am so new I don't even know how to describe my problem well, let alone identify potential solutions yet.

```
import SwiftUI
import AVKit

class SoundManager{
    static let instance = SoundManager()
    var player: AVAudioPlayer?
    
    enum SoundOption: String {
        case cheetah
        case dog
        case elephant
        case fox
        case frog
        case goldfish
        case gorilla
        case hippo
        case panda
        case parrot
        case pollarbear
        case tiger
        case wolf
        case zebra
    }
    
    func playsound(sound: SoundOption){
        guard let url = Bundle.main.url(forResource: sound.rawValue, withExtension: ".m4a") else {return}
       
        do {
            player = try AVAudioPlayer(contentsOf: url)
            player?.play()
        } catch let error {
            print("Error playing sound. \(error.localizedDescription)")
        }
    }
}


struct SoundBootcamp: View {
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack{
            Text("First Test Application")
                .lineLimit(1)
                .padding(10)
                .font(.system(size: 500))
                .minimumScaleFactor(0.01)
            HStack{
                ScrollView{
                    VStack{
                        Text("Aircraft")
                            .font(.system(size: 48))
                            .minimumScaleFactor(0.01)
                        Grid{
                            GridRow{
                                Button(action: {SoundManager.instance.playsound(sound: .cheetah)}, label: {
                                    Image("airliner")
                                        .resizable()
                                        .aspectRatio(contentMode: .fit)
                                        .cornerRadius(15)
                                })
                                Button(action: {SoundManager.instance.playsound(sound: .cheetah)}, label: {
                                    Image("biplane")
                                        .resizable()
                                        .aspectRatio(contentMode: .fit)
                                        .cornerRadius(15)
                                })
                                Button(action: {SoundManager.instance.playsound(sound: .cheetah)}, label: {
                                    Image("cargoplane")
                                        .resizable()
                                        .aspectRatio(contentMode: .fit)
                                        .cornerRadius(15)
                                })
                                Button(action: {SoundManager.instance.playsound(sound: .cheetah)}, label: {
                                    Image("gliderplane")
                                        .resizable()
                                        .aspectRatio(contentMode: .fit)
                                        .cornerRadius(15)
                                })
                                
                            }
                            GridRow{
                                Button(action: {SoundManager.instance.playsound(sound: .cheetah)}, label: {
                                    Image("hangglider")
                                        .resizable()
                                        .aspectRatio(contentMode: .fit)
                                        .cornerRadius(15)
                                })
                                Button(action: {SoundManager.instance.playsound(sound: .cheetah)}, label: {
                                    Image("helicopter")
                                        .resizable()
                                        .aspectRatio(contentMode: .fit)
                                        .cornerRadius(15)
                                })
                                Button(action: {SoundManager.instance.playsound(sound: .cheetah)}, label: {
                                    Image("hotairballoon")
                                        .resizable()
                                        .aspectRatio(contentMode: .fit)
                                        .cornerRadius(15)
                                })
                                Button(action: {SoundManager.instance.playsound(sound: .cheetah)}, label: {
                                    Image("rocket")
                                        .resizable()
                                        .aspectRatio(contentMode: .fit)
                                        .cornerRadius(15)
                                })
                                
                            }
                            GridRow{
                                Button(action: {SoundManager.instance.playsound(sound: .cheetah)}, label: {
                                    Image("seaplane")
                                        .resizable()
                                        .aspectRatio(contentMode: .fit)
                                        .cornerRadius(15)
                                })
                                Button(action: {SoundManager.instance.playsound(sound: .cheetah)}, label: {
                                    Image("spaceshuttle")
                                        .resizable()
                                        .aspectRatio(contentMode: .fit)
                                        .cornerRadius(15)
                                })
                                Button(action: {SoundManager.instance.playsound(sound: .cheetah)}, label: {
                                    Image("zeppelin")
                                        .resizable()
                                        .aspectRatio(contentMode: .fit)
                                        .cornerRadius(15)
                                })
                                
                            }
                        }
                        .padding()
                        Text("Example Category")
                            .font(.system(size: 48))
                            .minimumScaleFactor(0.01)
                        Grid{
                            GridRow{
                                Button(action: {SoundManager.instance.playsound(sound: .cheetah)}, label: {
                                    Image("cheetah")
                                        .resizable()
                                        .aspectRatio(contentMode: .fit)
                                        .cornerRadius(15)
                                })
                                Button(action: {SoundManager.instance.playsound(sound: .dog)}, label: {
                                    Image("dog")
                                        .resizable()
                                        .aspectRatio(contentMode: .fit)
                                        .cornerRadius(15)
                                })
                                Button(action: {SoundManager.instance.playsound(sound: .elephant)}, label: {
                                    Image("elephant")
                                        .resizable()
                                        .aspectRatio(contentMode: .fit)
                                        .cornerRadius(15)
                                })
                                Button(action: {SoundManager.instance.playsound(sound: .fox)}, label: {
                                    Image("fox")
                                        .resizable()
                                        .aspectRatio(contentMode: .fit)
                                        .cornerRadius(15)
                                })
                            }
                            GridRow{
                                Button(action: {SoundManager.instance.playsound(sound: .frog)}, label: {
                                    Image("frog")
                                        .resizable()
                                        .aspectRatio(contentMode: .fit)
                                        .cornerRadius(15)
                                })
                                Button(action: {SoundManager.instance.playsound(sound: .goldfish)}, label: {
                                    Image("goldfish")
                                        .resizable()
                                        .aspectRatio(contentMode: .fit)
                                        .cornerRadius(15)
                                })
                                Button(action: {SoundManager.instance.playsound(sound: .gorilla)}, label: {
                                    Image("gorilla")
                                        .resizable()
                                        .aspectRatio(contentMode: .fit)
                                        .cornerRadius(15)
                                })
                                Button(action: {SoundManager.instance.playsound(sound: .hippo)}, label: {
                                    Image("hippo")
                                        .resizable()
                                        .aspectRatio(contentMode: .fit)
                                        .cornerRadius(15)
                                })
                            }
                            GridRow{
                                Button(action: {SoundManager.instance.playsound(sound: .panda)}, label: {
                                    Image("panda")
                                        .resizable()
                                        .aspectRatio(contentMode: .fit)
                                        .cornerRadius(15)
                                })
                                Button(action: {SoundManager.instance.playsound(sound: .parrot)}, label: {
                                    Image("parrot")
                                        .resizable()
                                        .aspectRatio(contentMode: .fit)
                                        .cornerRadius(15)
                                })
                                Button(action: {SoundManager.instance.playsound(sound: .pollarbear)}, label: {
                                    Image("polarbear")
                                        .resizable()
                                        .aspectRatio(contentMode: .fit)
                                        .cornerRadius(15)
                                })
                                Button(action: {SoundManager.instance.playsound(sound: .tiger)}, label: {
                                    Image("tiger")
                                        .resizable()
                                        .aspectRatio(contentMode: .fit)
                                        .cornerRadius(15)
                                })
                            }
                            GridRow{
                                Button(action: {SoundManager.instance.playsound(sound: .wolf)}, label: {
                                    Image("wolf")
                                        .resizable()
                                        .aspectRatio(contentMode: .fit)
                                        .cornerRadius(15)
                                })
                                Button(action: {SoundManager.instance.playsound(sound: .zebra)}, label: {
                                    Image("zebra")
                                        .resizable()
                                        .aspectRatio(contentMode: .fit)
                                        .cornerRadius(15)
                                })
                            }
                            
                        }
                        .padding()
                        Text("Letters")
                            .font(.system(size: 48))
                            .minimumScaleFactor(0.01)
                        Grid{
                        }
                        .padding()
                        Text("Numbers")
                            .font(.system(size: 48))
                            .minimumScaleFactor(0.01)
                        Grid{
                        }
                        .padding()
                        Text("Shapes")
                            .font(.system(size: 48))
                            .minimumScaleFactor(0.01)
                        Grid{
                        }
                        .padding()
                        Text("Colors")
                            .font(.system(size: 48))
                            .minimumScaleFactor(0.01)
                        Grid{
                        }
                        .padding()
                    }
                }
                VStack{
                    Image("zebra")
                        .scaledToFit()
                    Text("Example")
                }
                .frame(maxWidth: .infinity)
            }
        }
    }
}

#Preview {
    SoundBootcamp()
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for posting the code.

You might want to think about trying to avoid so much duplication in the code. For example, you could use a function to create each button. Something like:

```swift
private func gridButton(imageName: String, sound: SoundManager.SoundOption) -> some View {
    Button(action: {SoundManager.instance.playsound(sound: sound)}, label: {
        Image(imageName)
            .resizable()
            .aspectRatio(contentMode: .fit)
            .cornerRadius(15)
    })
}
```

To show the selected item as a large image somewhere else in the view, you just need a state variable that can be updated whenever a button is pressed. Something like:

```swift
struct SoundBootcamp: View {

    @State private var selectedImageName: String?

    private func gridButton(imageName: String, sound: SoundManager.SoundOption) -> some View {
        // see notes
    }

    var body: some View {
        VStack{
            Text("First Test Application")
                .lineLimit(1)
                .padding(10)
                .font(.system(size: 500))
                .minimumScaleFactor(0.01)
            HStack{
                ScrollView{
                    // content as before
                }
                VStack{

                    // Show the selected image here
                    if let selectedImageName {
                        Image(selectedImageName)
                            .scaledToFit()
                    }
                    Text("Example")
                }
                .frame(maxWidth: .infinity)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The function that creates a button could then be updated to set the image in the button callback. Something like this:

```swift
private func gridButton(imageName: String, sound: SoundManager.SoundOption) -> some View {
    Button {
        SoundManager.instance.playsound(sound: sound)
        selectedImageName = imageName
    } label: {
        Image(imageName)
            .resizable()
            .aspectRatio(contentMode: .fit)
            .cornerRadius(15)
    }
}
```

---

*EDIT* Following up on your comment, here is how the first grid row  would look if you were to use the function to create the buttons:

```swift
GridRow{
    gridButton(imageName: "airliner", sound: .cheetah)
    gridButton(imageName: "biplane", sound: .cheetah)
    gridButton(imageName: "cargoplane", sound: .cheetah)
    gridButton(imageName: "gliderplane", sound: .cheetah)
}
```

What you might also like to consider, is to factor-out the different grid sections into separate computed properties. This might make it easier to manage the code. Something like:

```swift
var aircraft: some View {
    VStack{
        Text("Aircraft")
            .font(.system(size: 48))
            .minimumScaleFactor(0.01)
        Grid{
            GridRow {
                gridButton(imageName: "airliner", sound: .cheetah)
                gridButton(imageName: "biplane", sound: .cheetah)
                gridButton(imageName: "cargoplane", sound: .cheetah)
                gridButton(imageName: "gliderplane", sound: .cheetah)
            }
            GridRow {
                // middle row
            }
            GridRow {
                // last row
            }
        }
        .padding()
    }
}

var animals: some View {
    // like aircraft
}

// + other sections in a similar way
```

The scrolling part could then be simplified to the following:

```swift
ScrollView {
    VStack {
        aircraft
        animals
        letters
        numbers
        shapes
        colors
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much. I appreciate it so much and think I understand almost everything in your explanation. Could you give an example of what a new button/grid item used would look like?

Comment: Pleased to have been able to help! Answer updated with more elaboration - I hope I've understood your comment correctly and this is what you were interested to see.